# How to prevent pushes to a private repository in Github

Tags: github, version-control

We have a repository in GitHub. We want a group of developers to be able to view and fork this repository. But we'd like to prevent them from committing to our branches. Instead, we want this group of developers to fork the repo and create pull requests to contribute. Is there any way to achieve this in GitHub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access control is no longer available for private repositories. Both read and write access is given to the collaborators.

If a collaborator will have only read access to a repository, you must create an organization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add collaborator to your repository and give them just read access, look following article:

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/

Comment: This article is about adding collaborator. I already added the developers as collaborators, and that allows them to push to my repo. But I do not want them to be able to push directly to my repo. That was the problem all along.

Comment: If collaborator will have only read access, he/she will not be able to push directly to repository.

Comment: Can you check the link sent above and show me where I can assign a read-only access to a collaborator?

Comment: Look image from 6th step: "Select the user from the drop-down menu."

Comment: Oh, thank you. But I believe this feature is not present anymore. Because I can't see that drop down menu in GitHub.com. Can the help page be outdated?